# .NET MVC - C# foreach loop not working in IE11. Only last value in loop being returned

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, foreach, view

I have a View in my .NET MVC application that is supposed to return and display Model data, that is being read from an Excel file using the ExcelDataReader package.

My view contains a foreach loop that displays each value from the model, and displays that value in a div. Here is my current code:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model.StudentData)
   {
    <div>@item.FirstName</div>
   }
```

The problem I am having is that when this loop runs in my application, only the last value in the Model is being returned and is displayed in each div, but ONLY when I run the application in Internet Explorer 11. When I run this application using Chrome or Edge, the loops displays the model values correctly in each generated div.

For example:

```
model values             how Chrome/Edge returns data            how IE11 returns data
------------             ----------------------------            ---------------------
    4                                4                                     8
    3                                3                                     8
    9                                9                                     8
    8                                8                                     8
```

Is there something about the way I am looping through the StudentData model that needs to be changed so that it is compatible with the IE11 browser? I set a breakpoint at the end of the loop to verify that each value for `item.FirstName` was being returned correctly. I am convinced that it has something to do with the browser compatibility. Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image: IE11 View Source using for-loop in place of foreach to better illustrate problem]

Comment: Did you `View Source` in each browser? Are those values what you are seeing in each `View Source` or in the browser itself?

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills Yes, I checked the View Source in each browser, and only in IE11 is each generated div pointing at the last value. I actually tested this with a simple for loop. @for(int a = 1; a < 10; a++){ <div>@a</div> and got the same result. For the simple for-loop example, each generated div will display 9.

Comment: Cool - so that clearly shows that the `View Source` is correct (so please delete your earlier comment stating otherwise). But the browser is rendering it incorrectly. So that is a client side issue - not a server side one. ASP.NET MVC is working fine. The issue might be CSS or JS or something else - you'll need to use the dev tools in IE11 to work out why it is showing 9 when the HTML says 1 or 2 or whatever.

Comment: BTW, in future, to do `View Source` you right click in the browser and click `View Source` (or `View page source` or something similar).